# echo javascript in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to get data returned by AJAX after success. But It's returning the whole Javascript which I am echoing in the PHP file. What I really need is just the words which my JS is printing on the page.

Here is the Javascript code -

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(o) { 
       if (!o && o.status) return;
       if (o.status == 'connected') {
         document.write("connected");
       } else if (o.status == 'not_authorized') {
          document.write("unauthorized");
       } else {
          document.write("loggedOut");
       }
    });

  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
```

I want to compare the returned data `(data== connected, not_authorized, loggedOut)` and show respective html elements after comparing the returned data with `if..else` in AJAX success.

I would be thankful if someone helps me out of this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post your php code?

Comment: <?php
?>
The above Javascript
<?php
Rest of my php code
?>

Comment: The PHP script called by your AJAX post should only output the data needed to successfully fulfill the AJAX request. If you need to output Javascript for use elsewhere, you should do that in a separate script (or at least ensure that the Javascript output does not occur when called via AJAX).

Comment: there is nothing else than one div element on the page. and the JS in php prints the required thing, but for some kind of reason. Its returning the whole script after AJAX success :(

Comment: Yes can you post the rest of your php code, your javascript looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous and I would suggest posting the entire context.

I'll hazard a guess anyways. It seems as if you are trying to execute the Javascript after a successful AJAX call but in a PHP file. That won't work because JS only executes in a browser context. You can either execute and return plain strings from your PHP or you can use JSONP and the function you have pasted in the callback.